# Geolocalizacion en php

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy tratando de sacar mi ubicación por medio de la `api` de `google maps` implementada en `php` y `javascript` pero al momento de tratar de obtenerla me sale un `warning`, que es el siguiente:

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See
>   https://goo.gl/rStTGz for more details.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el código completo? Tiene toda la pinta de que estás usando la URL del API de google sobre http en vez de sobre https. Tanto Chrome como otros navegadores están marcando como inseguros los orígenes de datos que se obtienen a través de HTTP, por ser fácilmente vulnerables a ataques man-in-the-middle, secuestro de sesión, modificación en el aire de los datos (pudiendo inyectar código malicioso en la respuesta), etc... Sustituye `http://www.googleapis.com` por `https://www.googleapis.com` allá donde lo veas en el código.

Answer (score 3):

En google Chrome te permite únicamente acceder a la ubicación desde un sitio seguro con certificado SSL, podes probar en otro navegador o configurar uno.

Comment: En base a la poca información de la pregunta, esta es una respuesta válida, no hay motivo para poner negativo. Intenten comprobar por su cuenta en Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox y se darán cuenta a lo que se refiere @Abner.

Comment: @fredyfx Puse negativo porque creí que se refería a la ubicación geográfica y no a la dirección web.